# Django: Page not found (404) and not getting data from models in templates

Tags: django, view, models

I have been following along with a YouTube tutorial and even though I follow along exactly as he does it, I get the 404 error below. I have also been having no luck getting data from models into my templates. Even if the template loads, it will just come through as blank. ( I can upload an example of this as well) It loads static content but not dynamic content from the database. Anyone know why this may be? I have a guess it might be something in my settings.py? Thank you!

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/band/
```

My project is setup like this:

```
atmos_v4/
    atmos_v4/
       init__.py
       settings.py
       urls.py
       wsgi.py
    band/
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        models.py
        urls.py
        views.py
    db.sqlite3
    manage.py
    static/
         css/
             ...
         img/
             ...
         js/
             ...
         media/
             ...
    templates/
             band/
                 band.html
```

My band/models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
import datetime

class Band(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    date_founded = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
```

My band/view.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from band.models import Band

def band(request, band_id):
    band = Band.objects.get(pk=band_id)
    return render_to_response('band/band.html', {'band':band}, RequestContext(request))
```

My band/urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^(?P<band_id>\d+)/$', 'band.views.band'),
    )
```

my atmos_v4/urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView 

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html")),
    .
    .
    .
    (r'^band/', include('band.urls')),
)
```

My band.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <title></title>
  </head>
    <h1>{{ band }}</h1>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

My settings.py file:

```
"""
Django settings for atmos_v4 project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'y=3ey3sv8lm1j358(2bgthtx0bzy_cjaxug@2npx029nfs@5i%'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'beer',
    'band',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'atmos_v4.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'atmos_v4.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

from os.path import join

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)

STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    STATIC_PATH,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to the URL `"/band/"` in your browser, but you haven't defined a urlpattern for that URL: you've defined `"/"` and `"/band/<id>/"`. Either go to the root page, or find the ID of an existing band object and go to that page.

You would almost certainly be better off doing the official Django tutorial, rather than following a random YouTube video.

Comment: Thank you. I understand what my issue is now. I never defined /band/ in urls. Yeah, I have gone through a few different tutorials at this point, but I'm really new to django so a lot of it goes in one ear and out the other, but I'm starting to get the hang of things through watching multiple people do it over and over.